# Inputing and printing a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am just starting to dive into 2D arrays and I am having some trouble why my output is producing a line of data rather than the dimensional matrix. All help is appreciated! Thank you!!

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

int x, y, i, j;
int m[10][10];


setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

while (1) {
    printf("Number of rows? ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if (x == 0) 
        break;
    printf("Number of columns? ");
    scanf("%d", &y);

    printf("Enter matrix values row by row: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &(m[i][j]));
        }
    }
printf("Matrix read:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            printf("%d", m[i][j]); 
        }
    }
```

Imputed data:

```
Number of rows? 2
Number of columns? 2
Enter matrix values row by row: 
1 2 3 4
```

Output:

```
Matrix read:
1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out why your current program is printing the line, go through the printing loop, and look at all points where you are printing the values.

You will notice that it will be something like this:

> print "1", print "2", print "3", print "4".

So, the program just does that. It prints the numbers without any other "formatting" around.

You can do something like this:

```
printf("Matrix read:\n");
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        printf("%d ", m[i][j]); 
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Notice there's a space after the number in the literal "%d ".
And then, notice that a new line is printed after every inner `for loop` (which corresponds to a row).

*Note*: You may want to use more descriptive names. Eg: `row` instead of `x`
 and `column` instead of `y`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helped

Answer (score 0):

Your program is perfectly fine. It is printing the matrix in correct order too. However if you just want to format the output in a matrix format, just print "\t" and "\n" after the inner and outer loop respectively.

```
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        printf("%d\t", m[i][j]); 
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```